# Changing Label (in-use as buttons) Color by adding a class. **Using Jquery and Html**

Tags: html, jquery, css, radio-button

So I want to make a function within Jquery where I could change the colors of my labels (linked to hidden radio input) accordingly to which radio input is selected...

[image: True]

[image: False]

```js
function Buttonclick(radio, parentSelector) {
  var radioName = $(radio).attr('name');
  var parent = $(radio).parents(parentSelector);
  parent.find('input[type=radio][name=' + radioName + ']:not(:checked)')
    .next('label')
    .removeClass('active');

  $(radio).addClass('active');
}
```

```css
.button.active {
  background-color: #337ab7;
}

.btn-group {
  display: flex;
}

.button {
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: black;
  border: none;
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
}

.btn-true {
  border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
}

.btn-false {
  border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
}

input {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="btn-group">
  <input type="radio" onclick="Buttonclick(this, .btn-group)" name="isSchool" id="t" value="true">
  <label class="btn-true button" for="t" id="trueButton">T</label>
  <input type="radio" onclick="Buttonclick(this, .btn-group)" name="isSchool" id="f" value="false">
  <label class="btn-false button" for="f" id="falseButton">F</label>
</div>
```

It's not working however, none of the colors are being changed. I'm only building a sample right now so I'm using a plain online IDE, so I'm not sure if that's how you properly source Jquery.

Any feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: You can't include a script and add code within it, that's incorrect syntax. It's `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>` **OR** `<script>// Your code goes here.</script>`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response, I went for the second method but the code is still not working.

Comment: To elaborate on @j08691 's comment, you'd need to load `jQuery` first in one `<script src="..."></script>` block, and write your own custom logic in a separate `<script> ... code here </script>` block. You need both, but cannot combine the two.

Comment: you have a syntax error here: `parent.find('input[type=radio][name=' + radioName + ']:not(:checked)')` that should be `parent.find('input[type=radio][name=' + radioName ]:not(:checked)')`. This was causing the error message you see in the console